# Ant PropertyRegex won't support capture group when in property

Tags: regex, ant

I'm trying to create an ant build target that supports var substitution dynamically.

```
<target name="replace_property" depends="init_ant_contrib">
    <propertyregex input="${replace_inboundproperty"
        property="${replace_outboundproperty}"
        regex="${replace_match}"
        replace="${replace_target}"
        global="true"
        override="true" />
</target>
```

so I load the properties file and i'm basically setting the vars as such:

```
replace_inboundproperty="/target/path/targetfile"
replace_outboundproperty=blah
replace_match="/target/(.*)/targetfile"
replace_target="\1"
```

so when I echo blah, I'm getting "1".  Now if I actually do this:

```
<target name="replace_property" depends="init_ant_contrib">
    <propertyregex input="${replace_inboundproperty"
        property="${replace_outboundproperty}"
        regex="${replace_match}"
        replace="\1"
        global="true"
        override="true" />
</target>
```

and echo blah, I'll get "path".

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing to allow the replace to use capture groups from a properties file / ant -D?  Using ant-contrib 1.0b3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that in the properties file, if you double escape it, it'll function correctly:

```
replace_target=\\1
```